# Resolving Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, .net-generic-math

I'm trying create a generic calculator class which can support arithmetic operations like add , sub & mul very basic. but I'm getting this below mentioned error. I'm getting a feel that I need to add generic constraint on 'T' to allow operation only on those type which support + operator. But not able to figure out the solution. Would be great help, if you can provide great explanation that will help me understand this fundamental part of it.

"Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Here is the code for add operation. please let suggest the resolution to fix this problem.

```
**//this approach works** 
using System.Numerics;
namespace dotnet_basic;
public class Calculator
{
    public T Add<T>(T num1, T num2)
      where T : INumber<T> => num1 + num2;

    public T Subtract<T>(T num1, T num2)
        where T : INumber<T> => num2 - num1;
}


**//Corrected the second approach now even this approach works**
namespace dotnet_basic;
public class CalculatorNew<T> where T : INumber<T>
{

    public T Add(T num1, T num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

}
```

Need to find out how this functionality can be achieved using the .net 6 or less than version 6. Once we have that answer this question can be closed.

Here is the code for achieving above mention functionality in .net 6 or less than version 6.

```
// solution from @peet
namespace dotnet_basic
{
    public class Calculator<T> where T : struct // Add constraint here, e.g., 'struct' for value types
    {
        public static T Add(T num1, T num2)
        {
            dynamic dynamicNum1 = num1;
            dynamic dynamicNum2 = num2;
            return dynamicNum1 + dynamicNum2;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i got the reason why second approach was not working , it 's because type that Add method was taking is same as the Type that CalculatorNew is taking. I have corrected the second approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since .NET 7 you can use [the generic math interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math):

```
public class Calculator<T>
    where T : IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
    public static T Add(T num1, T num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Before .NET 7 the classic approach is building an expression:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    private static Func<T, T, T> _add;

    static Calculator()
    {
        var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        _add  = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,T,T>> (
                Expression.Add(left, right),
                new ParameterExpression[] { left, right }
            ).Compile();
    }
    
    public static T Add(T num1, T num2)
    {
        return _add(num1, num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank Shingo, How does achieve this is .net version <7.

Comment: i tried the above solution , check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/WmhQq0 .I'm still getting same error

Comment: I tried first approach , it works fine but with second approach it is giving error

Comment: Added the classic approach, if you find it trouble, you can also use peet's solution.

Comment: @sameer the method name should be `Add`, without the generic parameter `<T>`.